# How to warm cache for Facebook Like Button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

We are having troubles getting a correct preview of a facebook like.

**Description of the behaviour**

- The [Facebook debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) shows that there is no scraped data. [image: Facebook cache is empty]
- When clicking the like button for the very first time the preview looks like this. [image: Broken preview]
- After this the debug tool shows that there is a warm cache now. [image: Facebook cache is warm now]
- Also the preview is working fine now. [image: Preview working now]

I tried to warm the cache by fetching the data via the debug tool using "Fetch new scrape information" but that did not help with the preview.

Is there any other way to actively warm the facebook cache in order to fix the like preview for the first like?

Comment: You can [request a scrape](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects#selfhosted-update) of your articles at the time you publish them via API. (No guarantee that this will help though, because manually scraping it should achieve the same thing, but you said in your case it didn’t.)